# How can I form the matrix of sums of two arrays of vectors in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays `a` and `b`, of lengths *n* and *m*, containing vectors of length *d*, that is, `a[i].shape == (d,)` and likewise for `b`, for all `i`.

I want to form the matrix `A` of sums of these vectors, so that

```
A[i, j] == a[i] + b[j]
```

so `A` will be of shape `(n, m, d)`.

I know that I can use [`numpy.add.outer`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html#numpy.ufunc.outer) to get a matrix `M` of shape `(N, d, M, d)` containing all possible sums of *all components of* all vectors in `a` and `b`, and then my matrix `A` would be given by the formula

```
A[i, j, k] = M[i, k, j, k]
```

However, other than writing for loops I don't know how to turn `M` into what I need, and I need to do this in the most efficient way possible.

Ultimately I want to end up with the matrix of sums of squares of these vectors by doing `(A**2).sum(axis=2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
A = a[:, None, :] + b[None, :, :]
```

You could also replace `None` with [`numpy.newaxis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html#numpy.newaxis). They are the same thing, but `numpy.newaxis` might be easier to understand. I will note that you can also just do

```
A = a[:, None, :] + b
```

but I think the other way makes it more clear what is going on.

Comment: Just wanted to note that up until now I'd been using another way, calling `numpy.subtract.outer` and then filtering out the bits I wanted with `numpy.diagonal`, but the method in this answer is much better because it's more memory efficient.